# Control source address for whois queries

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, whois

is it possible to execute the command "whois" and choose the outgoing ip for the query?

I have mounted several IP's on my network interface "/etc/network/interfaces" for ssl porpuses, but would be great to use them also for querying.

And would be this possible also with IPv6?

I patched now the kernel with NAT66, but still don't know how I can set up querying through ipv6?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for misunderstanding the question the first time... you should use `iptables` to SNAT to the source address to your SSL address.  I add another interface address (172.16.61.5/29) below on eth0 to simulate the same dynamics...

**Sourcing IPv4 whois queries from 172.16.61.5**

*Before (Sniffing a query of `whois -h whois.arin.net <address>`):*

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ sudo tshark -i eth0 tcp and port 43
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
  0.000000 172.16.61.6 -> 199.71.0.49  TCP 55089 > nicname [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0
```

Note that my source address is 172.16.61.6...

*Set my source address for all TCP traffic to `tcp/43`:*

```
# Send all IPv4 whois queries from 172.16.61.5
sudo ip addr add 172.16.61.5/29 dev eth0
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p TCP --dport 43 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.61.5
sudo iptables -t nat -vnL
```

*After (Sniffing a query of `whois -h whois.arin.net <address>`):*

Now my address is 172.16.61.5...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ sudo tshark -i eth0 tcp and port 43
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
  0.000000 172.16.61.5 -> 199.71.0.49  TCP 55091 > nicname [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0
```

To remove the rule from the table...

```
# Remove the rule... (assuming it is the first nat POSTROUTING rule...)
sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING 1 -t nat
```

**Sourcing IPv6 whois queries from 2607:fcff:1001:100:202:55ff:dead:beef**

The IPv6 option requires a kernel with [NAT66](http://lwn.net/Articles/451914/)... see [HE.net's NAT66 installation notes](http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/n/nf/nfnat66/INSTALL) and [Packetpushers: Thank goodness for NAT66](http://packetpushers.net/thank-goodness-for-nat66/)

```
# IF you have an SNAT66 kernel...
#     Send all IPv6 whois queries from 2607:fcff:1001:100:202:55ff:dead:beef
sudo ip -6 addr add 2607:fcff:1001:100:202:55ff:dead:beef/64 dev eth0
sudo ip6tables -t nat66 -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p TCP --dport 43 -j SNAT66 --to-source 2607:fcff:1001:100:202:55ff:dead:beef
sudo ip6tables -t nat66 -vnL
# Remove the rule... (assuming it is the first nat POSTROUTING rule...)
sudo ip6tables -D POSTROUTING 1 -t nat66
```

I haven't got time to prove out the `NAT66` portion right now... my research indicates that the syntax above is correct though

Comment: I believe the OP wants to send the query out a specific interface address, not query a specific host.

Comment: To use the nat66 rule, you need to ensure that your whois server resolves to an ipv6 address...  that is a dns problem, not an iptables problem.   One easy workaround is to put a static mapping in /etc/hosts